# Check the perm 'Create Database' in PostgreSQL as well as in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I would like to check the perm in PostgreSQL db as well as I do it via this command
'`SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, 'DATABASE', 'CREATE DATABASE')`' for the SQL server.

What is the best way to do the same in PostgreSQL?
I didn`t find the similar function in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The privilege to create a new database is stored in `pg_roles`

To check if a specific user can create a new database:

```
select rolcreatedb
from pg_catalog.pg_roles
where rolname = current_user; --<< or replace with a specific user name
```

If you want to see all roles that are allowed to create a new database

```
select rolname
from pg_catalog.pg_roles
where rolcreatedb;
```

Comment: thanks, I am trying to do it for the current user without filtering by rolname column as it is implemented in MS SQL HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME. Do you know how to do it better than below?
I can do it something like that:

`select rolcreatedb from pg_catalog.pg_roles where rolname in (select current_user)`

Comment: Then use `where rolname = current_user` in the first query